# How to compute residues at infinity using Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis

If a complex function $f$ has a singularity at $\infty$, I know that a way to compute the residue at $\infty$ is

$$\text{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z)=-\text{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2} f \left( \frac{1}{z} \right).$$
But can I compute this residue by using the Laurent series expansion of $f$ around $\infty$, just as we do with singularities in $\Bbb C$? If that's the case, if I find the Laurent series of $f(1/z)$ around $0$:
\begin{equation}
f(1/z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n, 
\end{equation}

is $\text{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z)=a_{-1}$? Or do I have to take the $-1$-th coefficient of the series
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{z^2} f(1/z)= -\frac{1}{z^2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty -a_nz^{n-2},
\end{equation}
which would be the coefficient of $z^{-1}$, that is, $-a_1$.

Another question: if I'm asked to find the principal part of the Laurent series of $f$ around  $\infty$, do I have to take the princpal part of the first or of the second series?

I'm asking this question because I haven't found any example where the residue at $\infty$ is computed by using the Laurent series expansion, so if you have an example it would be great to know it.

Comment: Like you say, it's $-a_1$. $a_{-1}$ would be the residue at zero of a Laurent series.

Comment: The product of them? Why?

Comment: That period is a period!

Comment: the residue at a pole is the ("oriented") coefficient of the first "infinite power" - at $\infty$ this is the coefficient of $z$ so indeed $-a_1$, where the $-1$ comes because of the inversion in the circle boundary that takes the inside (so the usual residue at a finite point given by a counterclockwise integral on the boundary) to the outside (the residue at $\infty$ but now the boundary is viewed clockwise from $\infty$ so we need to switch signs); the principal part of a Laurent series at infinity is the polynomial part (same idea - the function is infinite there not on the $1/z^k$ part)